# Performing text data inside loops

Tags: java, text, for-loop, data-mining, bigdata

I have a Json file which is 1 Terabytes in size. Each `Json Object` is a text with 500-600 words. There are 50 million Json objects.

Now this is what I have to do with this Json file. I need to insert 200-300 words and a percentage value into a web page. Once this is done, the web application will read the entire Json file checking whether the inserted words are available in any Json object, and what is the percentage of the availability. If the availability percentage is higher than the percentage I inserted then this application will also keep track of words available in Json Object compared to the input list and words missing in Json Object compared to the input list.

I felt reading 1TB is too big, so I did a trick. I converted the text in every `Json Object` into hash (this hash represents any word with 3 characters) and saved it into a text file. Now the hash in every new line of this text file represents the text in that Particular Json Object. This text file is 120GB big. 50 Million lines.

My problem is that reading and performing the above job is still harder. It takes hours of time to complete! Why? Because the application read "every" line in this Hash, search which words are available and which words are not. So this "checking" algorithms are running for 50 million times!

Is there any way I can reduce the time of this operation and do it within few seconds? I know applications in chemistry and genetic medicine does the exact same thing within seconds! I am open to all the solutions, whether it is a Big data solution, data mining or a simple fix, whatever.

PS: I thought of a Hadoop based solution but purchasing lot of computers. That is a huge cost, even running in Amazon is double cost!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you have to go in the direction of a reversed index like lucene. The size of a reversed index is more influenced by the number of different words has by the number of documents. When looking up a word you directly get the ids of the documents containing it and thus the number of such object and thus the percentage. Simple so far. I guess a small cluster with 10 - 30 machines or so should be fine. Maybe elastic search is a good joyce here.

Comment: I do not have money to get 10 machines yet, main issue at the moment.

Comment: I'd say with a reversed index you're much better than now no matter how many machines. Minutes should be possible with an average desktop machine. After several hours for building the index of course. More machines will improve index building as well as access times.